# Overdamped Fokker-Planck equation with general force field (gradient + curl)

Tags: diffusion, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am looking for a general formulation of the [Fokker-Planck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation) equation for diffusing particles in a general force field $F = -\nabla U + \nabla\times A$ in the [overdamped](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/695721/226902) regime ([Smoluchowski](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/533066/226902) equation).

So far I have only found literature taking $A=0$. The diffusion tensor could be isotropic - like for a diffusing sphere far from any boundaries. I would appreciate any hint/reference on that topic.

Comment: Very interesting question! Related, for a potential force: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/556859/226902. For the general case: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/436947/226902 (the fact that the force is a potential one is not specified). Also (general case): https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/583344/226902