# Problem in derivation of Smoluchowski Equation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, diffusion, non-equilibrium, fluctuation-dissipation

I am trying to derive Smoluchowski equation using Fokker Planck equation. I am following the book ''Non Equilibrium Statistical Mechanics'' by Robert Zwanzig. I am attaching a screenshot of a few pages of the book.

**I am having issues with going from Equation 2.51 to 2.52. Can anyone please help with this, i.e. give a step by step solution?**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Presumably you would use 2.47?

Comment: I tried plugging in Eqn. 2.51 in 2.47 (replacing p/m=dx/dt), but could not make anything out of it.

Comment: This is just a matter of plugging (2.51) into the Fokker-Planck equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the left hand side of 2.50 to zero which is what "dropping the second derivative on the left hand side" means and solve for dx/dt.